# How to retrieve multiple json fields from json string using get_json_object

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark-sql

I am working in Scala programming language. I have a big json string. I want to extract some fields from it based on its path. I want to extract bunch of fields based on input collection Seq[Field]. So I need to call the function get_json_object multiple times. How can I do it using get_json_object? Is there any other way to achieve this?

When I do

```
var json: JSONObject = null
val fields = Seq[Field]() // this has field name and path 

var fieldMap = Map[String, String]()
for (field<- fields) {
  fieldMap += (field.Field -> get_json_object(data, field.Path))
}
```

I get `Type mismatch, expected: Column, actual: String`

And when I do lit(data) in above code. e.g.

```
get_json_object(lit(data), field.Path))
```

then I get

```
found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Column
[ERROR]  required: String
```